# Pass id from angularjs within django url

Tags: angularjs, django

I have created a filtered search list to search for some items from the database and show them in a list view. 
What I am trying to do is to display the items as links to their details pages.
since I am working with django and AngularJS there is a conflict between the {{ }} from both of them, so I have written the following code:

```
myApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
                   $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
                  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
        });
```

but when I tried to pass the id of the clicked item to the url, it doesn't work any more.
I am trying to do it the same way I did before using AngularJS but I am getting the following error:

> Reverse for 'line_details' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['baierlab/lines/line/(?P[0-9]+)/details']

The code now is like this:

The url for the details page:

```
url(r'^lines/line/(?P<line_id>[0-9]+)/details', views.line_details, name='line_details'),
```

In the head of the Template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

        myApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
                   $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
                  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
        });

        myApp.controller('FilterInputCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope) {

            $scope.items1 = [];

            {% for line in lines %}

                 $scope.items1.push
                 ({
                    id:{{ line.id }},
                    name:'{{ line.name }}',
                 });

            {% endfor %}
        });
    </script>
```

In the Body:

```
<body>

    <div id="selection_list" class="container item_padding">

        <div ng-controller="FilterInputCtrl" >

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="item1" placeholder="Enter your item">
                    <br />
                    <ul class="list">

                        <li ng-repeat="x  in items1 | filter:item1 | orderBy:'name'">
                            <a href="{% url 'line_details' x.id %}">//x.name//</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error that you get is very natural. The statement `{% url 'line_details' x.id %}` is being processed at server level, far before angular takes over at client level.

This is an often misconception in beginner web development. You need to clearly separate the logic of django and angular. The former makes things that happen in your server. It prepares a response which comes to the client (browser), where angular fires up and "compiles" (as angular likes to name it).

Personally I deal with this in the following way:

In the Django template I have a specific `<script>` section that defines js options which the server prepares for angular, including any urls to use:

```
<script>
    var o = {
        url: '{% url 'line_details' %}',
        // ...
    };
</script>
```

Please also note that you need to remove the parameter from your url include it using http get, eg: `lines/line/details?id=x`. This is also easier to manipulate later in angular using the `$http` object.

Then you need to build your url within your controller and bind it in your `<a>` link.

Of course the above method is not the only one, and with certain requirements is complicated, but you get the general idea.

In symmary, separate your django logic from your angular logic, easier to debug and develop.